# Is cloaking your site for disqus comments good for SEO?

Tags: google, googlebot, bing

I use "disqus" as the commenting platform on my website. There is quite a bit of SEO relevance for the comment content but since its generated through JAVASCRIPT. I can't get the best of it. Can I use cloaking as a technique so that I can display the disqus comments in a div when the googlebot is fetching it and when use the regular JS from disqus for its better user experience when a user is ....

Comment: NEVER serve different content to bots or humans. :)

Comment: Well the content is not different... It's the same content ... However there is a difference in terms of presentation... the script tag generates the content in an asynchronous way and after cloaking for the bot it will generate the same content in a synchronous way readable by the bot ....

Comment: Google (not sure about the other) has some progress in excecuting javascript with their bot. So I'd go with 'keep it the way you want for your users'

Comment: Interesting... Do you have evidence for this ??

Comment: a quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061844/do-googles-crawlers-interpret-javascript-what-if-i-load-a-page-through-ajax

Comment: That's a good resource but doesn't imply google can crawl ajax content...

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little bit confused what your asking. If your asking if Google can read your disqus then yes it can, if your serving it a different way then please make your question more obvious what exactly your doing and a moderator will evaluate your question shortly.